# Reemplazar caracter en un string conociendo su ubicacion en R

Tags: r, string

Tengo armada una función que scrapea precios y los vuelca a un dataframe. El problema es que dependiendo de si el producto tiene promoción o no ese día, cambia el formato del número que me devuelve: en algunos casos usa punto y en otros coma como separador decimal y a veces incluye el punto de los miles y a veces no. Por ejemplo, las primeras tres entradas que tengo son algo asi: 1.250,60 - 355.7 - 2340.00

Mi mejor idea hasta ahora fue, dentro de la funcion, identificar la ubicación del separador decimal usando:

```
posicion <- nchar(price)-2
```

Y cambiar lo que esté en esa ubicación por un símbolo distinto para después reemplazarlo con un replace o gsub de forma sencilla. Lo que no tengo claro es como especificar que quiero que use el nchar como posición a reemplazar. Probé:

```
price <- mutate(price = gsub(posicion, "&", price[posicion]))

substr(price, posicion, posicion)<-"&"
```

Pero ninguna funciona

Alguna idea de como hacerlo o alguna forma mas sencilla de resolverlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluando lo ejemplos que has dado, dónde todos los números tienen una parte decimal, con distinta longitud, lo que se puede hacer, es dividir ésta de la parte entera usando expresiones regulares y luego limpiar los puntos y comas:

```
ejemplo <- c('1.250,60', '355.7', '2340.00')

tmp <- gsub("(.*)[^\\d](\\d*)$","\\1|\\2", ejemplo, perl=TRUE)
tmp <- gsub("[\\.,]", "", tmp)
tmp <- gsub("[|]", ".", tmp)


as.numeric(tmp)
[1] 1250.6  355.7 2340.0
```

Comentarios:

- En primer lugar con `"(.*)[^\\d](\\d*)$"` capturamos la parte entera y la decimal, el patrón básicamente dice: (cualquier cadena)(un no número + todos los números hasta el final de la cadena). Mediante `gsub()` separamos las dos partes poniendo un `|` en el medio
- Con `gsub("[\\.,]", "", tmp)` borramos todos los puntos y las comas
- Por último con `gsub("[|]", ".", tmp)` reemplazamos el pipe separador por un punto, y lo que resta es convertir las cadenas a números.